# "Revert if Unchanged" large number of files in Plastic SCM

Tags: version-control, plasticscm

I'm a new Plastic SCM user, coming to it with Git and Perforce experience.

I had two copies of a local set of files, and copied one on top of the other to make sure that I had all of the files. Plastic SCM seems to have automatically checked out all of the files within these folders. However 90% of them are identical.

**How can I revert or cancel my checkout on all the identical files**, so I can only submit those with changes? In Perforce I would do this with "Revert if unchanged" or "Reconcile offline work".

There are thousands of files and I don't want to do diff and revert each one manually. Also I don't want to make a commit with thousands of files where only a few are changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to this right after posting it!

1. In the Pending Changes tab, select all the files you want to revert.
2. At the top, click the drop-down next to "Undo changes" and select "Undo unchanged".

That's it!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can simply uncheck this option and Plastic will avoid counting it as changed files.
[Plastic SCM preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPqIX.png)